# Assign array to Smarty and then parse it using foreach

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have an array from a mysql query that i want to use in smarty to display a list of options using foreach.

To be more exact i have a language list in a mysql table and i want to display all the languages in a html selector also i want to display the current selected language.

My query:

```
public function genLanguageSchema()
{
    $get = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT language FROM cms.language_schema WHERE status="ENABLED"');
                $get->execute();

    return $langList = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The php code:

```
$lang = $db->genLanguageSchema();
    $sch  = array(
        'language' => $lang['language']
        );

$template->assign('currentLanguage', 'Romana');
$template->assign('availableLanguages', $sch['language']);
```

The template code:

```
{if $show_language_chooser}
            <tr>
                <td style="width:25% !important"><label for="language_field">Website language</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="language_field" id="language_field">
                        {foreach from=$availableLanguages item=language}
                            <option value="{$language}" {if $currentLanguage == $language} selected="selected" {/if}>{$language}</option>
                        {/foreach}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {/if}
```

And the problem is that my code only shows the current language in the selector.

Kind regards!

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the value of `$sch['language']` is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to remove `[language]` from $lang assignment into php code?

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Can you post a print_r og $lang?

Comment: Output: 1. I dont really think that the variables are the problem. I believe that its something related to the query.

Comment: Print_r the $availableLanguages in smarty